# Solving for $x$ using $\ln$

Tags: logarithms

I have an equation as follows:

$\ln(a)x + \ln(b) (1 - x) = \ln(c)$

I'd like to solve for $x$, but I think what I've come up with is wrong

$\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)x + \ln(b) = \ln(c)$

$\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)x = ln\left(\frac{c}{b}\right)$

$x = \frac{\ln\left(\frac{c}{b}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}$

Comment: Do you mean $x\ln a+(1-x)\ln b=\ln c$?

Comment: yes, sorry, that would be better notation, wouldn't it?

Comment: What you have is right! In contrast, the answer you accepted is (as of now) not right when $b = 1$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$x\ln a+(1-x)\ln b=\ln c$$
$$x\log_ba+1-x=\log_bc$$ 
$$x(\log_ba-1)=\log_bc-1$$
$$x=\frac{\log_bc-1}{\log_ba-1}=\frac{\log_b(\frac cb)}{\log_b(\frac ab)}$$

Comment: You could even avoid changing base. Cheers

Comment: Yea, but it was just to look good! Cheers! @ClaudeLeibovici.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Unfortunately, this answer is wrong because of the change of bases. For example try $(a,b) = (e,1)$. Then $x = \ln(c)$ but the expression in this answer is undefined. The morals of the story are: (1) Do not do more than you need to, otherwise you risk needing more than you want to; (2) Do not use identities before you check the requirements. =)